# Android actionbar submenu items displayed on top of the actionbar instead of below the bar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I need to show the submenu below the bar, not on top of the bar itself.

Copying my actionbar xml below

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_pages"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="withText|always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_pages"
        android:title="">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Placeholder"></item>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

In the activity (App also has a navigation drawer)

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: The same issue is here (Android 5.1). After several years of stumbling upon such "features" here and there while developing for Android, I must say that Android is very frustrating platform, alas.

Answer (score 5):

Simply.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>

    <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks!

android:overlapAnchor isn't supported at API level 15 (which I am targeting), so I had to put this XML into my res/values-v21/styles.xml file, and then I removed the android:overlapAnchor setting for my normal res/values/styles.xml.  This got rid of the errors and warnings, and it works great now!

Answer (score 1):

**Preamble**

As usual, I faced a strange problem while developing an Android app, tried to find a solution and landed to this question. As it was in many cases before, there is no an answer. So I was compelled to solve the problem from scratch and now posting the answer with my workaround.

**Input**

I have an Android app with action bar and some menu items, which have to be extended with dropdown submenu. First attempt was to implement it as suggested by Android documentation. So I added new menu item `menu_sort` into existing action bar menu and sub-`menu` container into it:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:id="@+id/id1" android:icon="@drawable/ic_1"
         android:title="@string/id1" android:showAsAction="withText|always"/>
   ...

  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_sort"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_sort_selector"
    android:title="&#x25BE;"
    android:titleCondensed="&#x25BE;"
    android:showAsAction="withText|always">
    <menu>
      <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_sort_by_name"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:checked="true"
            android:title="@string/sort_by_name"/>
      <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_sort_by_priority"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:checked="false"
            android:title="@string/sort_by_priority"/>
      <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_sort_by_memory"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:checked="false"
            android:title="@string/sort_by_memory"/>
    </menu>
  </item>
</menu>
```

**Result**

The effect was exactly as described in the question: the submenu is displayed on top of the action bar. Here is the screenshot taken on Android 5.1.1:

[image: problem with dropdown submenu on top of its parent action bar]

I played with many options and code snippets - nothing helped. Finally I came to the following

**Solution**

First, move all the submenu into a separate menu layout, say, `menu/sorting.xml`, and remove it from `menu_sort` item of the main menu (shown above).

Second, modify or create `onPrepareOptionsMenu` event handler with the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
  // as solution utilizes PopupMenu,
  // take care about older Android versions if necessry
  // if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

  // here goes most crazy part: we use menu id
  // to retrieve corresponding view, automatically created by OS;
  // imho, this is a hack, and menu item should have getView() method or similar;
  View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.menu_sort);

  // by the way, menuItemView could probably be null under some circumstances

  // create a popup anchored to the view (menu item)
  final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
  // API 14
  // popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.sorting);
  // API 11 (HONEYCOMB)
  popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sorting, popupMenu.getMenu());

  // process popup clicks as appropriate
  popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
    {
      switch(item.getItemId())
      {
        // ... place some code
      }
      return true;
    }
  });

  // bind the popup to the item menu
  menu.findItem(R.id.menu_sort).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
    {
      popupMenu.show();
      return true;
    }
  });

  return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: properly positioned dropdown submenu under action bar - workaround]

Now the dropdown is displayed as expected from very beginning.

Comment: it's better to use listener in onOptionsItemSelected instead onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: it's better to move this code
`
 menu.findItem(R.id.menu_sort).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
    {
      popupMenu.show();
      return true;
    }
  });
`

from onPrepareOptionsMenu to onOptionsItemSelected

Answer (score 0):

@Stan's solution doesn't work for me, so here's my way to implement sub-menu on top of ActionBar (but below the main-menu of course):

I've created 2 xml files: ***menu_main.xml*** and ***menu_more.xml*** located in res/menu directory

The first one 'menu_main.xml' contain the menu:

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!-- our addMenu doesn't have sub-items-->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_note_add_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/action_add"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<!-- our moreMenu which show drop-down menu when clicked-->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_more"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/action_more" <!--in text: "more"-->
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

And the second one 'menu_more.xml' contain the drop-down menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!-- This menu will be hidden by default-->
<!-- But will be visible when moreMenu with '@+id/action_more' is clicked-->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_settings" <!-- In text: "Settings"-->
    android:visible="true"/>

</menu>
```

Here is what previous menus look like:

[result-after-add-2-xmls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvd0p.png) (i have not enough 10 reputation to display image)

 In the activity, i've overridden this method:

> public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

In the previous method, i get reference to the main menuItem (in this case is menu with ***@+id/action_more*** located in ***menu_main.xml*** file), then set ***setOnMenuItemClickListener*** on it and finally, declare and set up a ***PopupMenu*** instance to manage and display sub-menu items:

```
// show popup menu when menuMore clicked
menu.findItem(R.id.action_more).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
    {
        // get reference to menuMore item
        View menuMore = findViewById(item.getItemId());
        // create a popup anchored to the view (menuMore)
        // notes: if declare and set up PopupMenu Outside of this onMenuItemClick()
        // then it'll not work!
        // Because: the view you put into PopupMenu() could be null
        final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), menuMore);
        // inflate 'menu_more.xml' layout file
        // which contain all sub-items of menu
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_more, popupMenu.getMenu());

        // process popup clicks on sub-items
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
            {
                switch(item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.action_settings:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "showing SettingsActivity..",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    // more items go here
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        popupMenu.show();
        return true;
    }
});

return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
```

And here is final result:

[final-look-drop-down-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GM42.png)